# If a method is returning an instance of another class then what should be the return type of the method?

Tags: c#

I want a method to return more that 1 values. To do so, I have made those values as properties in a different class and declared the instance of that class in my method. Now I am using that instance to assign values to those property and my return statement is:
return instance;

What should be the return type of the method??

```
<return type??> someMethod{
---
--
var instance=new AnotherClass();
return instance;
}
```

Comment: I would question this architecture.  This is usually a really bad idea.  Without any code -1.

Comment: Why would you do `var instance=new AnotherClass();` when you know the Instance is of Type `AnotherClass` ? I'm curios what's wrong in doing `AnotherClass instance = new AnotherClass()` .

Comment: There's absolutely nothing at all wrong with your way. In fact, a lot of people prefer the explicit type. Some people - like me - dislike typing the same information literally twice in the same row and use 'var' which means 'Compiler, figure out the type yourself' (look up 'type inference' for more). It's just a stylistic choice here

Comment: @Amit: just a habit, no specific reason.

Comment: The issue I am having is when i am trying to call this method in yet another class. I am getting an error with reference type when i am trying to store the value what this method is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you declare the 'instance' variable? That needs a type too.
Your method would return exactly that.

```
var instance = new ReturnValues(); // instance is of type ReturnValues
```

so if you want to

```
return instance;
```

your method would need to be

```
ReturnValues YourMethod() { /* do stuff here, return your instance */ }
```

Depending on what you need to return you might also want to consider adding `out` arguments to your method or looking at the built-in `Tuple` class. Nothing wrong with returning your own type/object instance though.